# Rearrange list of dictionaries moving elements from another list of dictionaries to head

Tags: python, performance, sorting, python-3.8

(I am using Python 3.8) The problem is as follows: I have the following data

```
items = [{season: 3, id: 1}, {season: 5, id: 2}, {season: 10, id: 3}, {season: 8, id:4}]
```

And I would like to rearrange this list moving to the head the elements from seasons, e.g., 8 and 10. For that, I have another list with the elements from that subset:

```
items_to_top = [{season: 10, id: 3}, {season: 8, id:4}]
```

*I know this is not the most efficient way to do this, but it has to be like this since I have to respect some interfaces*. In order to move them to the top of the former list I am doing

```
 for item in items_to_top:
    items.remove(item)
    items.insert(0, item)
```

This operation is safe since `items_to_top` is extracted from `items`, therefore is a closed set.

I am looking for a more efficient/faster way to do this since when `items` grows (around 30k elements) and `items_to_top` grows as well (around 7k elements) the loop takes close to 1 minute to finish.

I have tried to transform everything to `set` but I can't since my data is unhashable (dicts) and inside the values of the dicts are also unhashable types (lists).

Comment: Since you mention that `items_to_top` are extracted from `items`, can't you delete them at that time? `remove` searches the whole list looking for a matching value and is rather inefficient.

Comment: Hi. I can't do that since I have to respect those interfaces I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set of tuples using the values of your dictionaries and create a new list like so:

```py
top_set = {(d[season], d[id]) for d in items_to_top}
new_items = items_to_top + [d for d in items if (d[season], d[id]) not in top_set]
```

The problem here is that everytime you use `items.insert(0, item)` you're creating a new list from scratch. Aditionally, the `remove` needs to search for the correct value from the beginning to the end of the list.

**EDIT:** Another approach, since you can't hash all the elements in the dictionaries.

```py
for item in items_to_top:
   items.remove(item)
   items.append(item)

items = items[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't work since I have other elements in the dictionaries which are non hashable.

Comment: In that case you should just append to the end of the list and then reverse it once done. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! This speeds ups the process ~1.5x. I will wait a little bit more to accept the answer, though.

Comment: Ah just realized you are expecting the _last_ item of `items_to_top` to be the _first_ of `items`. In that case, there's no need to reverse `items_to_top`. Minor speedups :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to store the indexes of the top items instead (or in addition to) the items_to_top list ?

That would allow a more direct reorganization of the items list using indexing instead of searches.

For example:

```
items = [{'season': 3, 'id': 1}, {'season': 5, 'id': 2}, 
         {'season': 10, 'id': 3}, {'season': 8, 'id':4}]

toTop = [2,3]

items = [items[i] for i in dict.fromkeys([*toTop,*range(len(items))])]


print(items)
[{'season': 10, 'id': 3}, {'season': 8, 'id': 4}, 
 {'season': 3, 'id': 1}, {'season': 5, 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact this was my first approach, to get the indexes and then reorder based on this. Nevertheless, this was even slower since it had to go through the list too many times as well...